# Terminal/Console Inside Browser

Tags: browser, applet, terminal

I have never tried modifying a web browser but is it possible to embed a program as a DOM element?

The simplest example would be to take that stupid Calculator program in Start>Applications and just place it in the top left hand corner of the browser. I don't need it to communicate with the browser, just sit there and be interactive.

What I really need is ssh access via a terminal (ie. Putty or Linux command line) but I don't want to use Anyterm or Ajaxterm which is incredibly slow. Similarly I don't want to force the user to open a new terminal. Although functionally it would be the same, it doesn't look or feel the same.

I'm sure there's a way to do this, I just have no idea where to start looking.

Cheers

Comment: see the embedded tag wiki to see why this tag has been removed.

Comment: @Ian Replaced it with Applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, it is possible. You would use some program which will be executed by some browser plugin (or other browser-specific mechanism) - or do this fully in JavaScript.

Possible mechanisms would be **Flash** (which will be executed by the browser's Flash plugin), or a **Java applet** (which will normally be executed by the Java plugin, though some browsers (like Konqueror) have their own way of embedding Java applets).

For client SSH access with a terminal, done in Java, an almost ready solution would be [JCTerm](http://www.jcraft.com/jcterm/), together with [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) (both from JCraft).

Comment: @Paulo, thanx for the link, it will help steer me in the right direction